# How to redirect output from pipe provided as argument to a variable

Tags: perl

So i've made functions to capture pipes

```
sub capture_stdout (&) {    
    my $s;
    open(local *STDOUT, '>', \$s);
    shift->();
    return $s;
}

sub capture_stderr (&) {
    my $s;
    open(local *STDERR, '>', \$s);
    shift->();
    return $s;
}
```

These work great. Now the challenge i am facing is, i want to make a function that takes the pipe(s) as arguments, and redirects all of them in a single sub.
I have yet been unsuccessful in making it work. So far I've cooked up something that compiles;

```
sub capture(@&) {
    my $c = pop;
    my $o = [];
    say {$_[$_]} $_[$_] for (0 .. $#_);
    open(local *{$_[$_]}, '>', \$o->[$_]) for (0 .. $#_);
    $c->();
    return $o;
}

use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper( capture *STDOUT, *STDERR, sub{ say 1; warn 2; } );
```

but it does not capture anything. I cant seem to figure out how to fix it. I'm convinced however that it is the `local *{$_[$_]}` that needs fixing, though i could be wrong.
The complete output is:

```
*main::STDOUT
*main::STDERR
1
2 at capture.pl line 15.
$VAR1 = [
      undef,
      undef
    ];
```

So then the question: Is it even possible to do what I'm attempting, and if so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: There's no pipe there, these are _filehandles_. I think you want to look at https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny. I believe that's what you are trying to recreate.

Comment: @simbabque That module does seem similar to what i want, although with more limited functionality as it only captures STDOUT and STDERR? whereas my sub would be able to capture any handle. Also as it is not part of core i cannot use it for my application.

Comment: @Noino Why not? [App::FatPacker](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) exists.

Comment: If you combine a solution from different answers, we prefer if you post your own answer and accept it. You can give credit where credit is due, and if you feel you don't deserve reputation from its upvotes, make it a community wiki post. But please don't include answers in questions.

Comment: melpomene's loop correctly handled empty list of captures, but your change introduced a virtually infinite loop.

Comment: @ikegami By empty list of captures you mean empty list of filehandles?
Will throw error ````Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference````. But you are correct, i should check arguments

Comment: No need to check the arguments; just revert your changes to get back a top-tested loop.

Comment: I'm not bothered by a thrown error tbh, the infinite loop in my case happens if you call the function without providing a code block.

Comment: https://eval.in/1059162 shifting burden to caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLUTION:

The final product, not nearly as convoluted as the original goto loop:

```
=pod

=item C<capture>

capture takes a list of pipes/filehandles, a code block or sub, optionally arguments to send to
said block and returns any captured output as a string, or an array of strings.

    my ($out, $err) = capture *STDOUT, *STDERR, sub { say 'faijas'; warn @_; }, 'jee';
    my $output = capture *STDOUT, sub { say 'jee'; };

=cut

sub capture(@&;@) {
    my (@o, @h);
    # walk through @_, grab all filehandles and the code block into @h
    push @h, shift while @_ && ref $h[$#h] ne 'CODE';
    my $c = pop @h; # then separate the code block from @h, leaving only handles

    # Really we want to do: open(local *{$_[$_]}, '>', \$o->[$_]) for (0 .. $#_);
    # but because of scoping issues with the local keyword, we have to loop without
    # creating an inner scope
    my $i = 0;
    R: open(local *{$h[$i]}, '>', \$o[$i]) or die "$h[$i]: $!" ;
    goto R if ++$i <= $#h;

    $c->(@_);
    return wantarray ? @o : $o[0];
}
```

Big thanks to @melpomene and @simbabque for helping me around the initial problem, and @ikegami for pointing out oversights.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that the effects of `local` are undone at the end of your

```
... for (0 .. $#_);
```

loop. By the time you call `$c->()`, the filehandles have their original values again.

So ...

- You want to localize an arbitrary number of variables.
- You can't use blocks (e.g. `for (...) { ... }`) because `local` is undone at the end of the scope it's in.
- You can't use postfix `for` because apparently it implicitly creates its own mini-scope.

The solution? `goto`, of course!

(Or you could use recursion: Use a block, but never leave it or loop back. Just localize a single variable, then call yourself with the remaining variables. But `goto` is funnier.)

```
sub capture {
    my $c = pop;
    my $o = [];

    my $i = 0;
    LOOP: goto LOOP_END if $i >= @_;
    local *{$_[$i++]};
    goto LOOP;
    LOOP_END:

    open(*{$_[$_]}, '>', \$o->[$_]) or die "$_[$_]: $!" for 0 .. $#_;
    $c->();
    return $o;
}
```

Effectively we've created a loop without entering/leaving any scopes.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks

Comment: I knew i cant do a ````for( ... ){ ... }````, but then somehow forgot about the scoping issue when i assumed postfixing wouldn't create its own. The goto looks horrible tho

Comment: You should definitely go and wash your hands after building this. And maybe your eyes. :D

Comment: @simbabque The final product i edited into my original post doesn't hurt my eyes at all tbh, but I'll wash the dirty goto off my hands just to be safe

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually switch out the file handles. To do that, first save the existing handles. Then create new ones that point into your output data structure. Once you've run the code, restore the original handles.

```
sub capture {
    my $c = pop;

    # we will keep the original handles in here to restore them later
    my @old_handles;

    my $o = [];
    foreach my $i (0 .. $#_) {

        # store the original handle
        push @old_handles, $_[$i];

        # create a new handle
        open my $fh, '>', \$o->[$i] or die $!;

        # stuff it into the handle slot of the typeglob associated with the old handle
        *{$_[$i]} = $fh;
    }

    # run callback
    $c->();

    # restore the old handles
    *{$_[$_]} = $old_handles[$_] for 0 .. $#_;

    return $o;
}
```

Comment: I haven't figured out yet why the `local` solution doesn't work.